# R define breaks

Tags: r

I want to define the following 6 breaks in R:

```
[00,10)
[10,20)
[20,30)
[30,40)
[40,50)
[50,60)
```

If I write `breaks=seq(from = 0, to = 60, by = 10)` I get the following

```
(0,10]  
(10,20]   
(20,30]    
(30,40]    
(40,50]    
(50,60]
```

How could I get it?

Comment: If I write `breaks=seq(from = 0, to = 60, by = 10)` I get nothing. Please provide complete examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `?cut`

> `right`: logical, indicating if the intervals should be closed on the
>   right (and open on the left) or vice versa.

Do you want

```
cut(seq(1,60,10), breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 60, by = 10), right = TRUE)
# [1] (0,10]  (10,20] (20,30] (30,40] (40,50] (50,60]
```

?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `cut(seq(1,60,10), breaks, include.lowest = TRUE, right = FALSE)`? At least that returns the upper table of the OP.

Comment: Yep, thanks, I confused given and desired output.